# Give the parametric equations of each faces of a cube (Correct my answer)

Tags: linear-algebra

**Give the parametric equations of each faces of a cube made by the vectors $\vec i, \vec j, \vec k$**

The professor told me that this is how I get the under face:

$\vec x = t1 \dot\ \vec i + t2 \dot\ \vec j , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $

He also told me (not sure if I understood correctly) that this is the right face :

$\vec x = [0,1,0] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,0,1] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $

So I figured, that I have to take a point + two vectors that goes in the direction to make the faces.

$\vec x = [0,1,0] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,0,1] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $

here are my other faces

$\vec x = [0,0,0] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,0,1] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $
$\vec x = [1,0,0] + t1 [0,1,0] + t2 [0,0,1] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $
$\vec x = [0,0,1] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,1,0] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $
$\vec x = [0,0,0] + t1 [0,1,0] + t2 [0,0,1] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1 $

Is this corrrect ?
And
Is it ok if I never use i j k explicitly in my equations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two vectors are the same, and you are missing one of the faces perpendicular to the $z$-axis:
$$
\vec x = [0,0,0] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,1,0] , 0 \le t1,t2 \le 1
$$
Otherwise, it looks good.

To make sure you have them all and didn't repeat, it helps to list each one in a descriptive way; e.g.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{perpendicular axis}&\text{which end}&\text{parameterization}\\
\hline
x&0&[0,0,0] + t1 [0,1,0] + t2 [0,0,1]\\
x&1&[1,0,0] + t1 [0,1,0] + t2 [0,0,1]\\
y&0&[0,0,0] + t1 [0,0,1] + t2 [1,0,0]\\
y&1&[0,1,0] + t1 [0,0,1] + t2 [1,0,0]\\
z&0&[0,0,0] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,1,0]\\
z&1&[0,0,1] + t1 [1,0,0] + t2 [0,1,0]\\
\end{array}
$$
where $0 \le t1,t2 \le 1$.